# Smart search results behaviour of compound index of multiple page types

Tags: search, lucene, kentico

Can someone confirm the behaviour of the `Smart search results` webpart when using a `Smart search filter` on a particular field, documentation [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k82/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-search-filters), when the index, and the expected results, are compound of multiple page types?

In my scenario I have 2 page types, one is always a child of the other, my hypothetical scenario would be a `Folder` and `File` types as an example.

I've configured the index with `Pages` type and `Standard` analyzer to include all `Folder` and `File` types under the path `/MyOS/%` on the tree.

The search page, includes the `Smart search results` webpart and a `Smart search filter`, a checkbox for the `File`'s field `FileIsHidden`.

What I'm trying to ascertain is the possibility for the results to include all folders that have a hidden field, as well as the files?

Client has a v8.2 license and now has a requirement similar to this scenario.

Thanks so much for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly what i would do is download the latest version of LUKE, it's a lucene inspector that allows you to run queries, inspect the data, etc.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/downloads

Your search indexes are in the App_Data/Modules/SmartSearch/[SearchName], now i am not sure if LUKE can query 2 indexes as the same time, however you can run hte same query against both and see if it's filtering out results one way or another.

If you are trying to query where a field must be a value, and the other page type does not have the field, it probably is filtered out.  What you need to do is use the lucene syntax to say "(classname = 'cms.file' and fileonlyproperty = '' OR classname <> 'cms.file')" so to say.

You'll have to test, but say the class name is cms.file and cms.folder, and the property is FileIsHidden, i think the syntax would be:

```
+((FieldIsHidden:(true) and classname:('cms.file')) OR (NOT classname:('cms.file'))
```

But you'll have to test that.

Comment: thank you Trevor valuable stuff, the client was happy with the separation, but we may address this at some point later. thanks.